# Get coordinates of select option with jQuery

Tags: jquery, coordinates, html-select, offset

I'm trying to get the coordinates of `<select> <option>`. Not position, but x, y coordinates. I cannot get it via `JQuery.offset()` or `position()` which only return me the coordinates of `<select>`.

Comment: Why do you need to do this? Can you post relevant code?

Answer (score 0):

As you've seen yourself, you can do this with:

```
$('#some-select option[value="3"]').position();
```

However, this will be *exactly the same* as if you did:

```
$('#some-select').position();
```

There is simply no way to get `x` and `y` coordinates of an `option` because this will vary wildly between browsers.